# Convert an List<object>to user defined class

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-5.0

I have some data that is object IEnumerable, how to do I convert it into class type, the name of class is option

```
    "option": {
  "id": 8204,
  "name": "250 ML",
  "price": 40.0,
  "status": 1,
  "archive": 0
}

   "option": {
  "id": 8204,
  "name": "250 ML",
  "price": 40.0,
  "status": 1,
  "archive": 0
}
class Option
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public long Price { get; set; }
        public long Status { get; set; }
        public long Archive { get; set; }
    }
```

so far tried =>

```
foreach (var VARIABLE_3 in (IEnumerable) VARIABLE_2)
                        {
                            if ( VARIABLE_3.ToString().Contains("option") && !VARIABLE_3.ToString().Contains("options"))
                            {
                                object[] values = ((IEnumerable)VARIABLE_3).Cast<object>().ToArray();
                                //Option[] values = VARIABLE_3.ToString().Cast<Option>().ToArray();
                                foreach (var VARIABLE in values)
                                {
                                    strStringBuilder.Append("VARIABLE: " + VARIABLE + "\n");
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing with this code? What is the datatype of `VARIABLE_2`?

Comment: The issue would be that it just produces a StringBuilder.

Comment: List<object> is the data type of VARIABLE_2

Comment: "data that is object IEnumerable" how, where from?  What you post is JSon and  `Json.Deserialize()` couldbe your best option.

Comment: maybe you are looking for something like this:
foreach(var VARIABLE_3 in (VARIABLE_2 as IEnumerable<Option>))...

Comment: tried json.deserilizer threw an exception of   Message "Could not cast or convert from System.String to .Library.Option." string
string st = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Option>(VARIABLE_3.ToString()).Name;

Comment: tried foreach throws an exception of object not set to an instance of an object

Comment: What is inside of `VARIABLE_3` ?

Comment: "option": {
  "id": 8204,
  "name": "250 ML",
  "price": 40.0,
  "status": 1,
  "archive": 0
}

Comment: How are you populating `VARIABLE_2`? The JSON you shared is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Because of the multiple options in your json string snippet you'll have to use the 

<LIST<Option>> 

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Option>>(jsonArrayObject);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JavascriptSerializer` or `Json.Net` serializer to serialize or deserialize Json string.

```
string jsonArrayObject = @"
[
  {     "id": 8204,
        "name": "250 ML",
        "price": 40.0,
        "status": 1,
        "archive": 0
  },
  {
         "id": 8208,
        "name": "Coke",
        "price": 0.0,
        "status": 1,
         "archive": 0
  }
]";
```

**Javascript Serializer**

```
List<Option> optionList = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.
                         JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Option>>(jsonArrayObject);
```

**Json.Net**

```
List<Option> optionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Option>>(jsonArrayObject);
```

Comment: this is in variable_3 List<Option> optionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Option>>(VARIABLE_3.ToString());

Comment: throws an exception of "Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[some.Library.Option]."

Comment: Do not use `VARIABLE_3.Tostring()` use that string variable which contains whole json string as I created in example `string jsonArrayObject`